# How to get Destination value from xml

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml. I need to get the value of Destination but it is returning null.

```
String samlp = document.getElementsByTagName("samlp").item(0).getTextContent();
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://192.168.1.112/TestWeb/faces/acs.jsp?ent1.com" ID="_acb47035be4f862af61804c2192ed58fa100eba4fc" InResponseTo="ONELOGIN_91dd1c8a-5053-42c5-acc8-111111111" IssueInstant="2018-12-06T05:19:32Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<saml:Issuer>https://example.com/test.php</saml:Issuer>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: There is no tag `samlp` in your document.

Comment: @talex I tried with samlp:Response also giving me null as well.

Comment: To understand why it doesn't work you have to read something about XML namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you looking for is:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("samlp:Response").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("Destination").getNodeValue()
```